# MySQL auto increment field on UPDATE (initially is NULL)

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table Order with these fields:

- ID (PK and with regular auto_increment)
- payment_date
- invoice_number

Initially Orders are created with payment_date and invoice_number with NULL values, so I could have these rows:

```
ID | payment_date | invoice_number
1  |     NULL     |     NULL
2  |   03/10/11   |      1
3  |   03/14/11   |      2
4  |     NULL     |     NULL
5  |     NULL     |     NULL
```

What I wanna do is when I update a row to fill the payment_date I need to update the invoice_number with the first available invoice_number. For instance, if I update the fifth row, the invoice_number would be '3'.

A first approach would be to SELECT the MAX() value for invoice_number and then add 1 to that value, but that would have concurrency problems, right?.

What do you think would be the best solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do the "Select MAX()"-solution if you're using SELECT FOR UPDATE - the dbms would handle the concurrency issues.
[SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: Same problem that I've commented above, I can't select from the same table I'm updating. Any thoughts?

Comment: you could declare a variable and select for update the max count into it and after that use the variable for the update statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: what would be the differences about using "FOR UPDATE" and not using it?. If "FOR UPDATE" locks the table, what would happen if another similar query arrives in that moment?

Comment: for update locks the rows of the tables - if an update would occour similar it would have to wait until the select for update has finished. so the next for update query had to wait until your update statement has finished - after that it would execute and return the new max value

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid concurrency problems, you can do this in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) or a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

And if you do something like this :

```
update table
set 
    column = 'something'
    column = (select max(id) + 1 from table)
where id = 123
```

You won't have concurrency problem either. When you're doing this update, the table is locked, so nobody else can update it while the query is running.

Comment: What he said... (Why to I always take too long to write answers...)

Comment: If use MAX() inside the update as you suggested, what would happen if another query is executed in that moment? Will they query be lost, or executed later?

Comment: @javi The other query will have to wait this one is finished. So it will be executed later. You can't "lose" a query without some kind of hardware failure.

Comment: Nice, I'll go for that approach. Just one more question: what about what Gambrinus suggested? Do I need to use SELECT FOR UPDATE for the MAX() query?

Comment: I've tried this solution but it gives me this error:
You can't specify target table 'Orders' for update in FROM clause